# If cell is empty, skip and go to the next

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with some code that will take a predefined range and copy data to a sheet with the same name as in column A. The issue that I am running into is if Column A has a blank cell, which is needed, then I get an error in which it reports back saying "Cannot call method "getRange" of null." If there is data in that cell then it works perfectly.

Some things that I have tried include filtering the range, however, the code still reads the range even though it is hidden. I have also tried writing an if/then statement but was not successful.

[I have a sample Google Sheet ready to go here to illustrate the blank space.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XIee6J_PCzBSfWi4q9we0X8uHAKllEs7JxD1xhmwCH0/edit?usp=sharing)

Here's a screenshot of the blank cell I am referring to:

[image: Screenshot of the blank cell I am referring to.]

Code in use:

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var master = ss.getSheetByName('Home');
var colWidth = master.getLastColumn();// last used col in masterSheet
var sheets = ss.getSheets();// number of sheets
var editRange = 'B2:B15';


function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Copy selected Rows to sheets", functionName: "copyRowsOnConditionV2"},
                     ];
  ss.addMenu("Copy functions",menuEntries);// custom menu
}

function copyRowsOnConditionV2() {
  var sheetNames = [];// array of existing sheet names
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();// number of sheets
  for(s=0;s<sheets.length;++s){sheetNames.push(sheets[s].getName())};

  var selectedfirstRow = ss.getRange(editRange).getRowIndex();
  var selectedHeigth = ss.getRange(editRange).getHeight()
  var selectedFullRange = master.getRange(selectedfirstRow,1,selectedHeigth,1);
  var data = selectedFullRange.getValues();
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
    if(data[n][0].length<16){
     var dest = ss.getSheetByName(data[n][0].toString().replace(/ /g,''));//find the destination sheet
     Logger.log(data[n][0].toString().replace(/ /g,''))
     var destRange = dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1);// define range
     master.getRange(selectedfirstRow+n,2,1,1).copyTo(destRange);// and make copy below last row
    }
  }
}
```

I guess what I am looking for is some sort of "If cell is blank then go to next cell" sort of code.

What I was thinking would work:

```
If(data[n][0].length==""{
// Do nothing

if(data[n][0].length<16){
// Do something
}
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get something like this to work?

**Edit**

I found that the original IF statement I posted just above was not in the correct syntax. I have since corrected it, however, still get the same error.

New If Else if Statement:

```
if(data[n][0].length=0){
//do nothing 
}
else if(data[n][0].length<1){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
    if (data[n][0]) {

     // do something;


     }
```

In the 'if' operator, the statement between the brackets will be evaluated as 'false' if the value is null, undefined or an empty string "".

Comment: This did the trick for me! Thank you for taking a look at my code and providing a solution.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Just be careful with using the 'if' statement with numbers - in JavaScript, it evaluates 0 to 'false' which is a bit counter-intuitive. For strings, this will do the trick though.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript "not" operator will test a value for `null`, `undefined` and an empty string, and return `true` if it finds any of those conditions. The "not" operator is an exclamation point.

```
if(!data[n][0]){
  Logger.log('tested true for NOT')
  continue;//execute the next loop
}
```